# add a column to a pandas.dataframe that holds the index of the closest point with a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge number of points stored with x and y coordinates and an additional value ('value_P')  in a pandas.dataframe so the dataframe looks like:

|  | x-coordinate | y-coordinate | value_P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 40 | 58 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 76 | 98 | 2 |
| 4 | 15 | 35 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 4 | 3 |

but with around 250000 entries, so i look for a efficient solution. I am trying to add a column that holds the row index of the closest other point. But only the distance between points with value_P!=1 to points with value_P==1 should be considered. Also i am only interested in the index for points where value_P!=1. Its difficult to explain but the desired output should be:

|  | x-coordinate | y-coordinate | value_P | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | NaN |
| 1 | 40 | 58 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 76 | 98 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 15 | 35 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 0 |

For row 1 the index is NaN because i am not interested in it, since value_P==1. For row 2 its 0, because the point from row 0 is the closest point with a value_P of 1.
I hope its understandable.
I found a solution that involves 2 DataFrame.apply(lambda x:...) functions but it takes a long time. Even if you dont have a concrete solution but an idea how to improve the performance it would be highly appreciated.
My current code is: (P_sort is the data and 'zuord' is the added column)

```
def index2(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,last_1):
    h = math.sqrt((x_1 - x_2) ** 2 + (y_1 - y_2) ** 2)
    return h

def index(x_1,y_1,x_v,y_v,last_1):

    df2 = pnd.DataFrame()
    df3 = pnd.DataFrame()
    df2['x-coordinate'] = x_v
    df2['y-coordinate'] = y_v
    df3['distances'] = df2.apply(
        lambda x: index2(x['x-coordinate'], x['y-coordinate'], x_1, y_1, last_1), axis=1)
    k=df3.idxmin()
    print(k)

    return k
last_1 = np.count_nonzero(P_sort[:, 2] == 1) - 1
df = pnd.DataFrame(P_sort,
                   columns=['x-coordinate', 'y-coordinate', 'value_P'])
number_columnx = df.loc[:, 'x-coordinate']
number_columny = df.loc[:, 'y-coordinate']
x_v = number_columnx.values
y_v = number_columny.values
x_v = x_v[0:last_1]
y_v = y_v[0:last_1]
df['zuord'] = df.apply(lambda x: index(x['x-coordinate'],x['y-coordinate'],x_v,y_v,last_1),axis=1)
```

I am new to programming so the code is kind of ugly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clarify what percentage of points have value_P==1? It affects what the best solution is.

Comment: Hello, yes the percentage is around 0.5%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I benchmarked four solutions, and the fastest approach is a KD Tree.

### Test Dataset

I randomly generated dataframes of various sizes to test the performance of each method.

```
def generate_spots(n, p=0.005):
    x_pos = np.random.uniform(0, 100, n)
    y_pos = np.random.uniform(0, 100, n)
    value_P = np.random.binomial(size=n, n=1, p=(1 - p)) + 1
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x-coordinate': x_pos,
        'y-coordinate': y_pos,
        'value_P': value_P
    })
    df = df.sort_values('value_P').reset_index(drop=True)
    return df
```

This generates a dataframe with n rows, with a probability p that each row is class 1. I also sorted it, because the original method seems to assume that the dataframe is sorted by P.

### Method 1: Original

I made some small changes to your code to get it to work for me:

```py
def method1(df):
    df = df.copy()
    last_1 = np.count_nonzero(df.loc[:, 'value_P'] == 1)
    number_columnx = df.loc[:, 'x-coordinate']
    number_columny = df.loc[:, 'y-coordinate']
    x_v = number_columnx.values
    y_v = number_columny.values
    x_v = x_v[0:last_1]
    y_v = y_v[0:last_1]
    df['index'] = df.apply(lambda x: index(x['x-coordinate'],x['y-coordinate'],x_v,y_v,last_1),axis=1)
    df.loc[0:last_1 - 1, 'index'] = -1
    return df
```

index() and index2() are defined the same way as your question. I also use -1 as a placeholder instead of NaN. No deep reason for this, just personal preference.

### Method 2: cdist

Scipy has a function called [cdist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) which takes the distance between each point among two arrays of points.

```
import scipy.spatial.distance

def method2(df):
    df = df.copy()
    first_P_class = df['value_P'] == 1
    target_df = df.loc[first_P_class][['x-coordinate', 'y-coordinate']]
    source_df = df.loc[~first_P_class][['x-coordinate', 'y-coordinate']]

    nearest_point = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(source_df, target_df).argmin(axis=1)
    df['index'] = -1
    df.loc[source_df.index, 'index'] = nearest_point
    return df
```

The cdist function is pretty much the same as what you're doing - it's just implemented in C rather than Python.

### Method 3: KD Tree

A [KD Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is a data structure designed to efficiently search for nearby points. You can use SciKit Learn to implement this.

```py
import sklearn.neighbors

def method3(df):
    df = df.copy()
    first_P_class = df['value_P'] == 1
    target_df = df.loc[first_P_class][['x-coordinate', 'y-coordinate']]
    source_df = df.loc[~first_P_class][['x-coordinate', 'y-coordinate']]
    tree = sklearn.neighbors.KDTree(target_df)
    nearest_point = tree.query(source_df, k=1, return_distance=False)
    df['index'] = -1
    df.loc[source_df.index, 'index'] = nearest_point.flatten()
    return df
```

### Method 4: fastdist

The Python package [fastdist](https://pypi.org/project/fastdist/) bills itself as a faster alternative to scipy's distance calculation methods. Ironically, I found this solution to be slower than cdist at all problem sizes.

```
from fastdist import fastdist

def method4(df):
    df = df.copy()
    first_P_class = df['value_P'] == 1
    target_df = df.loc[first_P_class][['x-coordinate', 'y-coordinate']]
    target_array = target_df.to_numpy()
    source_df = df.loc[~first_P_class][['x-coordinate', 'y-coordinate']]
    source_array = source_df.to_numpy()
    
    nearest_point = fastdist.matrix_to_matrix_distance(source_array, target_array, fastdist.euclidean, "euclidean").argmin(axis=1)
    df['index'] = -1
    df.loc[source_df.index, 'index'] = nearest_point
    return df
```

### Benchmarks

Each method was run ten times, with various sizes of dataframe, in random order. Here are the results of the benchmark. Note that both the X and Y axes are log-scale.

I didn't benchmark fastdist or the original method for more than 30,000 points, because it took too long.

[image: benchmark plot]

The fastest methods, in this benchmark, are the cdist method, for fewer than 1000 points, and KD Tree method, for more than 1000 points. At 250K points, the fastest solution is the KD Tree, taking only 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect someone to put that much effort into my question! I will not be able to implement your solution until after the holiday, but I am sure it will greatly increase the performance of my program. Thank you so much and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Merry Christmas to you as well!